# Getting Melon JS to work with my code

Tags: javascript, melonjs

This is a noob question but I have not worked to much with JavaScript as of yet. I have a game I am programming for class and so far everything looks okay but I cannot get my main.js file to recognize the me for melonJS which is what I am using as part of the game engine. The code is below:

main.js source code:

```
main.js:
// JavaScript Document
var jsApp = {
onload: function(){
    "use strict";
    if (!me.video.init('jsapp', 320, 240, true)){
        alert ("html 5 canvas is not supported by this browser.");
        return;
    }
    me.loader.onload = this.loaded.bind(this);
    me.loader.preload(resources);
    me.state.change(me.state.LOADING);
},
loaded: function(){
    me.state.set(me.state.PLAY, new Playscreen());
    me.entityPool.add("player", PlayerEntity);
    me.state.change(me.state.PLAY);
}
};
window.onReady(function(){
"use strict";
jsAPP.onload();
});
```

here is the my index code file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Adventure Game</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper" style="width:640px;    text-align:center;  margin-
left:auto;   margin-right:auto;">
  <div id="jsapp">
     <script type="text/javascript" src="melonJS.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="resources.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="screen.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="entity.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It looks like the code you provided should not have any problems accessing the `me` reference. It might help to have a look at the [melonJS boilerplate project](https://github.com/melonjs/boilerplate), which takes care of all this setup for you. At the least, you can be sure you'll start with a base foundation that is known to work. Also, out of curiosity, what's the exception or error message you get when you try to run your code?

Comment: jsAPP is not defined, and Prefixed Fullscreen API is deprecated. Please use unprefixed API for fullscreen. For more help https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API.  I worked out the issues with the me reference issue

Comment: JavaScript is case-sensitive, and you have defined the global variable as `jsApp`, not `jsAPP`

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript variables are case-sensitive; At the start of main.js, you declare a variable called `jsApp`. At the end of the same file, you reference `jsAPP`, which is not the same. Change the last one to `jsApp`, and it will advance a bit further.

See the [MDC Glossary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Variables) for more information:

> A JavaScript identifier must start with a letter, underscore (_), or dollar sign ($); subsequent characters can also be digits (0-9). Because JavaScript is case sensitive, letters include the characters "A" through "Z" (uppercase) and the characters "a" through "z" (lowercase).

Comment: Thank you I really appreciate the help